# What does this mean "封不觉心中这么想着"?

Tags: translation

I was reading a webnovel and i stumbled upon this and i am confused about the meaning of the phrase.
Does this mean he is thinking in his heart? There is a quote before this by the way.

Answer (score 1):

"封不觉 thought in mind."

Chinese language prefers that the heart thinks, not the brain thinks.

Answer (score 0):

If 封不觉 is not his name, then it means 'Feng (just) can't help thinking (like this)'

If his name is 封不觉， then it means 'Feng Bujue thinks like this.'

Answer (score 0):

I was reading two.
This mean how is he thinking in his heart.